# Ignite SQL error 50000 when inserting on refence table

Tags: mariadb, ignite

I'm currently researching on Ignite, and I used web-console's automatic RDBMS integration feature for my MariaDB persistent store.

This made ignite configure a cache for one of my reference table which has a many-to-many relationship, with 2 fields, both primary-keys.

Example Structure in the persistent store:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_category` (
  `USER_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `CATEGORY` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`USER_ID`,`CATEGORY`),
  KEY `FK48520EF2B4BDA303` (`USER_ID`),
  KEY `FK48520EF2C941D634` (`CATEGORY`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK48520EF2B4BDA303` FOREIGN KEY (`USER_ID`) REFERENCES     `ctrl_app_user` (`USER_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK48520EF2C941D634` FOREIGN KEY (`CATEGORY`) REFERENCES     `request_category` (`CATEGORY_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This made web-console configure the cache like this:

```
ArrayList<QueryEntity> qryEntities = new ArrayList<>();

QueryEntity qryEntity = new QueryEntity();

qryEntity.setKeyType("model.UserCategoryKey");
qryEntity.setValueType("model.UserCategory");
qryEntity.setTableName("user_category");

HashSet<String> keyFields = new HashSet<>();

keyFields.add("userId");

keyFields.add("category");

qryEntity.setKeyFields(keyFields);

LinkedHashMap<String, String> fields = new LinkedHashMap<>();

fields.put("userId", "java.lang.Long");
fields.put("category", "java.lang.Long");

qryEntity.setFields(fields);

HashMap<String, String> aliases = new HashMap<>();

aliases.put("userId", "USER_ID");

qryEntity.setAliases(aliases);

ArrayList<QueryIndex> indexes = new ArrayList<>();

QueryIndex index = new QueryIndex();

index.setName("FK48520EF2B4BDA303");
index.setIndexType(QueryIndexType.SORTED);

LinkedHashMap<String, Boolean> indFlds = new LinkedHashMap<>();

indFlds.put("userId", false);

index.setFields(indFlds);
indexes.add(index);

index = new QueryIndex();

index.setName("FK48520EF2C941D634");
index.setIndexType(QueryIndexType.SORTED);

indFlds = new LinkedHashMap<>();

indFlds.put("category", false);

index.setFields(indFlds);
indexes.add(index);

qryEntity.setIndexes(indexes);
qryEntities.add(qryEntity);

ccfg.setQueryEntities(qryEntities);

return ccfg;
```

I am able to retrieve data from ignite properly using its standard SQL.
However, when trying to insert data to that cache, I am getting error 50000 which according to Ignite documentation, is a query that is unsupported by ANSI-99.

Documentation also mentioned to take a look into the SQLException message but the message only mentioned the error 50000.

sample insert statement:

```
insert into USER_CATEGORY (USER_ID, CATEGORY) values (1, 1);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the error number for "duplicate key"?  I am wondering if there is already a row with (1,1) in it.

Comment: I'm not sure about the dup-key error code (not listed in error codes), but I made sure that there is no duplicates. with the combination of keys I am trying to insert.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you need to specify a schema name (cache name) for the query:

`insert into "YourCacheName".USER_CATEGORY (USER_ID, CATEGORY) values (1, 1);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my schema name is already defined in the connection string, I can insert data into other tables, just not this one.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue using your cache configuration but without success. Could you publish a small maven project on GitHub which will help to reproduce the error?

Answer (score 0):

So, for everyone who will experience this issue in the future, I've resolved the issue by removing the query entity keys.

```
keyFields.add("userId");

keyFields.add("category");
```

Ignite treats keys in a reference table/cache as unique, so both columns needed to be unique, this is not applicable for reference tables with many-to-many relationship since this design is bound to have duplicates for each column.

Thanks for those who took a look at this issue!~